# Show that there exists a sequence with subsequences converging to every rational number.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

> The total question is:
>
> (a) Give an example of a sequence with subsequences converging to $1, 2$, and $3$.
>
> (b) Give an example of a sequence with subsequences converging to every integer.
>
> (c) Show that there exists a sequence with subsequences converging to every rational
> number.

**My attempt**

For (a) I got $(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,\dots)$

For (b), I got $(0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4,\dots)$

Both of these I think are right, but I have no idea how to start on (c), much less an example for (c). If someone could explain what I should be doing, I'd be so grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: the rationals are countable.

Comment: $(b)$ is wrong, you just seem to have written the integers as a sequence. This doesn't work. You will have to be cleverer, but the idea of $(a)$ can be utilized for $(b)$ cleverly. Besides, every sequence must have a first term, so you cannot write $...-3,-2,...$ which is a double ended sequence.

Comment: Note that if $a_1,$ $a_2,$ $a_3,$ $\ldots$ is an enumeration of a countably infinite set, then the sequence $a_1,$ $a_1,$ $a_2,$ $a_1,$ $a_2,$ $a_3,$ $a_1,$ $a_2,$ $a_3,$ $a_4$, $\ldots$ is such that for each $a_n$ there is a subsequence **constantly equal to** $a_n$ (because each of the $a_n$'s gets revisited infinitely often in the (new) sequence). Note that this is a slightly stronger result than what was asked for.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon All I can think is having it be (0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, ...) which fixes the second part. Could it plainly be written as like $(a_n)$ = n, so like $a_5$=5, and thus this subsequence converges to 5?

Comment: @red You need to think about repetition of terms. See, if you want a convergent subsequence to a number, a way to artificially manufacture that is to have that term appear infinitely many times. For example, try : $0, -1,0,1,-2,-1,0,1,2,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,...$ and try to see what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example for (b) is wrong. There are no convergent subsequences of it.

Consider any countably infinite set $\{e_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Then consider the sequence $e_1, e_1, e_2, e_1, e_2, e_3, e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4, ...$

For all $n$, this sequence has a subsequence where every element is $e_n$.

Thus, for every countably infinite subset $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we can find a sequence above where for each $e \in E$, there is a subsequence converging to $e$. In particular, we can do this for $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence that:

- Move up from $-1$ to $1$ by increments of $1/2$
- Then down to $-2$ by increments of $1/3$
- Then up to $3$ by increments of $1/4$
- Then down to $-4$ by increments of $1/5$
- ...

is such that for any real $a$ it has a subsequence converging to $a$.

Answer (score 0):

For (c), if $n\geq 2$ has the prime factorisation
$$
n=2^\alpha3^\beta 5^\gamma \cdot ...
$$
with $\alpha, \beta, \gamma,....\geq 0$, define
$$
a_n=(-1)^\alpha \frac{\beta}{\gamma+1}
$$
Show that $a_n$ takes each rational number infinitely many times.